# Understanding animation fragment and animation view together

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, view

I right understanding that it is impossible to simultaneously perform the animation of the fragment and view.
I try to run view animation and fragment at the same time

```
private void startAnim(){
    mShowDarkOverlay = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mBackDarkOverlay, "alpha", 0f, 1f);
    mShowDarkOverlay.setDuration(100);
    mShowDarkOverlay.setStartDelay(0);
    mShowDarkOverlay.start();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,R.anim.paddle_fade_out)
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MyFragment())
            .commit();
}
```

But I only see the animation fragment.
I understand that the animation on the view runs in the main thread, and when it starts the animation of the fragments, the animation view is interrupted.
Is that right? Cannot be performed immediately animation view and fragment ?

**UPDATE**

I created test project. [github](https://github.com/Nikonov/fragandviewanim.git)

Open application - press button(add item) in action bar (waiting 3 seconds)- click button "2".
And we see the result. Animation View does not begin until you create the fragment.

Fragment blocks the main thread?
In my case the fragment need 2-3 seconds to be created.

I want to change the background and at the same time to change the fragment. Is this possible?

Comment: more code? Let me have a try.~

Comment: is your view in your fragment??

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FragmentCustomAnimationSupport extends FragmentActivity {
int mStackLevel = 1;
private TextView mTestAnimationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_stack);

    mTestAnimationView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    // Watch for button clicks.
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.new_fragment);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addFragmentToStack();
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Do first time initialization -- add initial fragment.
        Fragment newFragment = CountingFragment.newInstance(mStackLevel);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.simple_fragment, newFragment).commit();
    } else {
        mStackLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt("level");
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("level", mStackLevel);
}


void addFragmentToStack() {
    mStackLevel++;

    Animator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mTestAnimationView, "alpha", 0f, 1f);
    animator.setDuration(300);
    animator.start();

    // Instantiate a new fragment.
    Fragment newFragment = CountingFragment.newInstance(mStackLevel);

    // Add the fragment to the activity, pushing this transaction
    // on to the back stack.
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_slide_left_enter,
            R.anim.fragment_slide_left_exit,
            R.anim.fragment_slide_right_enter,
            R.anim.fragment_slide_right_exit);
    ft.replace(R.id.simple_fragment, newFragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}



public static class CountingFragment extends Fragment {
    int mNum;

    /**
     * Create a new instance of CountingFragment, providing "num"
     * as an argument.
     */
    static CountingFragment newInstance(int num) {
        CountingFragment f = new CountingFragment();

        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    /**
     * When creating, retrieve this instance's number from its arguments.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
    }

    /**
     * The Fragment's UI is just a simple text view showing its
     * instance number.
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_world, container, false);
        View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        ((TextView)tv).setText("Fragment #" + mNum);
        tv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.gallery_thumb));
        return v;
    }
}
```

}

I tried in SupportV4Demo, code above, animation of view and fragment played together. mTestAnimationView was a textView layouted above the fragment container(R.id.simple_fragment).